# How to enable flow.run_local_server() for HTTPs in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

My code was working accurate on localhost. But not when I try to host in DigitalOcean Droplet.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.auth.exceptions import RefreshError
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import argparse
import base64
import io, os
import shutil
import requests
from pebble import concurrent

class Drive:
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    extensions = {"csv": "text/csv", "mpeg": "video/mpeg"}

    def __init__(self):
        self.creds = self.load_credentials()
        if self.creds is not None:
            self.service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=self.creds)
        else:
            self.service = None

    @concurrent.process(timeout=45)
    def create_process(self):
        creds = None
        token_path = 'token.json'
        if os.path.exists(token_path):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_path, scopes=self.SCOPES)
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, self.SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(host="somedomain.com",port=443)
            with open('token.json', 'w') as token_file:
                token_file.write(creds.to_json())

        # Attempt to refresh the token
        try:
            print("refresh")
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error refreshing token:", str(e))
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, self.SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(host="somedomain.com",port=443)
            with open('token.json', 'w') as token_file:
                token_file.write(creds.to_json())

        return creds

    def load_credentials(self): 
        try:
            process = self.create_process()
            creds = process.result()  # Wait for the process to complete
        except TimeoutError:
            creds = None
            print("Task was canceled due to a timeout.")

        return creds
```

What I figured out is run_local_server() doesn't work on https.
My domain looks something like "https://somedomain.com"
that is, with SSL enabled.

How to make the above code workable in production ? please help

Comment: What is the error? what does >does not work  mean?

Comment: I mean in localhost, it was redirecting to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsomedomain.com%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&state=xxxx&access_type=offline` on a new tab. 

But it is not redirecting in production. 

According to https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html

It tells the run_local_server() is for local purpose only. Then what should I do for production ?

Comment: yes, please look into this thread: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/755 Since you seem to be interested in web server flow, i think function referred by you might not be ideal.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link but the method they are telling to use is `authorization_url` which doesn't return `creds` as like `run_local_server()` as in my code but the `authorization_url`. I am not clear how to implement this in my code. Can you please  give me a clue ? Also it's in my utils file so It will be not a good practice to use `from django.shortcuts import redirect` in utils for redirecting `authorization_url`